# Wrong Graphs for Ids (MOSFET)

Tags: transistors, mosfet, matlab

EDIT:
I have now obtained this graph, using the suggested changes. Does it look reasonable?
[image: Transfer Characteristics (measured vs calculated)add]

And this one maybe more clearer:
[image: new graph]

I'm writing a MATLAB script that employs Shockley's model to derive the values for K and Vt of a transistor. Upon determining these parameters, I utilize them within the framework of Shockley's model to compute a theoretical value for Ids. This theoretical prediction is then plotted alongside the experimentally measured value to evaluate the accuracy of the model. I have the data in the form of:

> Vds = 0.05V 
> Vgs0.05 = [values] 
> Ids0.05 = [values]

and similarly for Vds = 0.1V and 10V.
This is the model used:
K * (V_{gs2} - VT)^2

I solve for K and Vt by setting up a system of two equations and using the values of two measurements in the saturation region. I obtain four values (although there are only two print statements):

> K: 5.588945e-06 A/V^2  
> K: 3.173648e-04 A/V^2 
> VT: -1.257039 V 
> VT: 2.448081 V

Regardless of the values for K and Vt, the graphs look awkward:
[image: Model fit]

This is the original transfer characteristics for the measured data:
[image: Transfer Characteristics]
I don't understand how to make it plot better for the measured data.

EDIT: This is the raw data:

> % Vds = 0.05V
> Vgs005 = [0.202 0.396 0.601 0.808 1.001 1.208 1.396 1.591 1.813 2.014 2.206 2.411 2.605 2.805 3.015 3.202 3.415 3.605]; 
> Ids005 = [0.002*1e-6 0.002*1e-6 0.002*1e-6 0.036*1e-6 6.38*1e-6 6.75*1e-6 19.3*1e-6 33.4*1e-6 48.2*1e-6 59.8*1e-6 69.9*1e-6 79.5*1e-6 87.7*1e-6 95.2*1e-6 102*1e-6 108*1e-6 114*1e-6 120*1e-6];

> % Vds = 0.1V 
> Vgs01 = [0.202 0.406 0.603 0.803 1.010 1.202 1.406 1.607 1.799 2.004 2.200 2.406 2.609 2.805 3.022 3.207 3.404 3.597]; 
> Ids01 = [0.01*1e-6 0.01*1e-6 0.01*1e-6 0.04*1e-6 0.888*1e-6 8.88*1e-6 33.7*1e-6 63.8*1e-6 90.8*1e-6 116*1e-6 138*1e-6 158*1e-6 177*1e-6 192*1e-6 208*1e-6 220*1e-6 232*1e-6 243*1e-6];

> % Vds = 10V 
> Vgs10 = [0.202 0.404 0.612 0.802 1.00 1.208 1.416 1.604 1.809 2.011 2.200 2.418 2.615 2.805 3.034 3.202 3.408 3.602]; 
> Ids10 = [0.99*1e-6 0.99*1e-6 1*1e-6 1.04*1e-6 1.89*1e-6 12.7*1e-6 56.3*1e-6 134*1e-6 261*1e-6 426*1e-6 618*1e-6 877*1e-6 1.14*1e-3 1.43*1e-3 1.80*1e-3 2.10*1e-3 2.49*1e-3 2.87*1e-3];

This is how I compute K and VT:

```
Vgs1 = Vgs005(12); 
Ids1 = Ids005(12); 

Vgs2 = Vgs005(15); 
Ids2 = Ids005(15); 
 
syms K VT
eq1 = Ids1 == K * (Vgs1 - VT)^2;
eq2 = Ids2 == K * (Vgs2 - VT)^2;


sol = solve([eq1, eq2], [K, VT]);


K_value = double(sol.K); 
VT_value = double(sol.VT); 


fprintf('Värdet på K är: %e A/V^2\n', K_value)
fprintf('Värdet på VT är: %f V\n', VT_value)
```

Comment: Can you give us the raw data and the equations you used to arrive at your computed values for \$V_T\$ and K?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Thank you for your reply, I have now added that information in the last part.

Comment: Thanks. As in your last version of this question, you are using data that is invalid for calculating \$V_T\$. When \$V_{ds}\$ equals 0.05 or 0.1 V, it is less than \$V_T\$, and therefore in the Ohmic region. Use the data for \$V_{ds}=10V\$ to calculate \$V_T\$ and \$K\$.

Comment: The simplified equation you have been using applies only if the MOSFET is working in the saturation region (Vds > Vgs - Vt). This equation only describes the behavior of an ideal MOSFET in a saturation region nothing more. In the ohmic region (triode) the equation is different  Id = k( 2*(vgs- vt)*vds - vds^2 ).

Comment: @G36: Thank your for your response, I have recoded the script with your answer in mind. I have now uploaded the obtained graph in the document, does it look reasonable?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy : I appreciate your response, I have used Vds=10V to obtain the K and Vt value. I have uploaded the new graph in the question, does it look reasonable?

Comment: Now your plots look good to me.

Comment: The plots look "reasonable", but it appears as though there is a growing error as \$V_{ds}\$ gets bigger. I wonder if you might be able to give more "weight" to the higher \$V_{ds} / I_d\$ points. Of course, this might just result in a larger error at low \$V_{ds}\$. But if you are lucky, you might be able to get a closer fit. There are techniques for fitting polynomial data, but I don't have the inclination or time at the moment to go there.